# Xamarin.Android Detect camera disconnect

Tags: c#, xamarin, camera, xamarin.android, zxing

I use ZXing lib in my apk . Sometimes I have problem with my camera ( it's global problem ) and I get error message  . I get this when run default camera apk or some QRCode Scaner , but In my apk I have black screen -nothing else.
How Can I detect problem with camera ? I want catch this and show alert for user.

Comment: Did you add the android camera permission in Manifest ?

Comment: I haven't got problem with permission . 
I dont know how Can i catch information that camera not work (anather program witch used camera detect this situation ("Can't connect to camera")

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement broadcast receiver from camera. Check android docs for details about camera events